# Cannot leave voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord

My bot cannot leave a voicechannel, but it can join in anyone. I have 2 codes, one is "leave" and the other one is "stopstream", It said " Cannot read property 'channelID' of undefined" and "(node:11416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'voiceChannel' of undefined" with one complex code

I tried to use different code, one more complex than the other. And put "const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };" in the complex one.

```
//leave

const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };

exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {

   if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Please connect to a voice chanel, don\'t be afraid my child. Share you beautiful voice.');

   if (!message.guild.mne.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Sorry, I\'m not connected to the guild.');

   if (message.guild.me.voiceChannelID !== message.member.voiceChannelID) return message.chanel.send('Sorry, you aren\t connected to the same channel, I\'ll give you some PeterFriffinCoins, for free.');

   message.guild.me.voiceChannel.leave();

   message.channel.send('Leaving Channel... I\'m a free elf...')
}


//stopstream

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {

    client.leaveVoiceChannel(message.member.voiceState.channelID);
    message.channel.send('Thanks for tuning in!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in leave channel command

```
let authorVoiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
if(!authorVoiceChannel) return message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel")
if(authorVoiceChannel.id !== client.voiceChannel.id) return message.channel.send("We're not in the same voice channel")

authorVoiceChannel.leave()

message.channel.send("I left voice channel")
```